# Why am I seeing no difference between ConfigureAwait(false) and ConfigureAwait(true) here?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to create a proof of concept for a report I'm doing on `async`-`await`.

I made a sample piece of code

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    static async Task CreateATaskThatPrintsWhichThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread on line right before the bottom await = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            Task.Delay(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread on line inside bottom task action = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);                         
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Thread on line right before the bottom await = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread on line right before the bottom await = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Task printStuff = CreateATaskThatPrintsWhichThread();
            printStuff.ConfigureAwait(true);
            await printStuff;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread on line right before the bottom await = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

which I'm repeatedly running on .NET Fiddle and the results are sporadic:

```
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 14
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 14
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28


Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28


Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 53
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 53
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 28
```

etcetera. And when I change to `printStuff.ConfigureAwait(false);

```
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 99
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 99
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 87
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 36
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 99

Thread on line right before the bottom await = 45
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 45
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 36
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 36
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 45

Thread on line right before the bottom await = 25
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 25
Thread on line inside bottom task action = 12
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 12
Thread on line right before the bottom await = 25
```

Can someone clue me in to what the results "should" be, or maybe help me create a better example on .NET Fiddle?

(I'm also confused because I thought the line inside inside the `Task.Run` was basically guaranteed to be executed on a background thread)

Comment: Are you not finding it very confusing that half your logging uses strings that are indistinguishable from other strings already used in your logging?  Because I'm finding that confusing.

Comment: And why are you discarding the task returned by ConfigureAwait?

Comment: You should have gotten a warning from the compiler explaining the problem; did you ignore the warning?  Consider reading compiler warnings when you have some code that appears to be not working correctly; those warnings are trying to tell you why the code is not working correctly.

Comment: Re: "I'm also confused because I thought the line inside inside the Task.Run was basically guaranteed to be executed on a background thread" -- you have shown no evidence that the thread used for the execution is *not* a background thread. Change your logging to print out the result of `IsBackground` on the thread and you'll see that it always is a background thread.

Comment: But your fundamental question is about why you are seeing no difference in behaviour based on whether or not you require the continuation get executed on the current context. Rather than trying to characterize a *difference*, instead state what behaviour you *expect* to see when true, and then what you *expect* to see when it is false.  Are either of your expectations violated?  If not, then what's the problem?  If yes, then you have an incorrect expectation, so let's state what it is and dispel your incorrect belief.

Comment: To get a continuation to resume executing on the same thread is fairly nontrivial.  The thread has to co-operate and solve the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  The universal solution is a dispatcher loop.  Like the one you get from a Winforms, WPF or UWP app.  But not a console mode app.

Comment: Also, I am confused about what you're asking when you say "what *should* I be getting?" You *should* be getting the output you *are* getting, because *that is all legal output for the program you wrote*. What are you actually asking here?

Comment: And what is the point of making a Task.Delay and then *not awaiting it*???  This makes no sense at all; this means "go set an alarm and then do nothing when it goes off".  Why would you set an alarm in the first place if you intended to not do anything when it goes off, or even *wait* for it to go off? Significant portions of this code make no sense at all so it is very hard to figure out what the actual answer to your question is.

Comment: I suspect though that the thing that is puzzling you ultimately can be resolved by you considering this question: what does it mean to say "you are required to continue on this synchronization context" vs "you are *not* required to continue on this synchronization context" in a world where *there is no synchronization context to begin with*? I suspect that you have not internalized that console applications lack a synchronization context. This might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Answer (score 1):

The comments cover most of this, but as there is no answer yet, I think the answer you're after is that you have incorrectly concluded that `.ConfigureAwait(true)` means that after the `await`, the code will continue on the same thread as before.

This is true *in some cases*, notably those that have some form of message/dispatcher loop.  In these cases, when the pre-continuation code is complete, the `SynchronizationContext` captured is used to post a request back to the dispatcher to - when it next is able to - pick up the continuation and continue executing it on its thread.  The loop is typically spinning continuously and quickly, servicing UI concerns, and once the post is registered it will use one of its iterations to execute the continuation.

A console app has no such loop, and no `SynchronizationContext`, so the task of executing the continuation is instead queued to the thread pool, and any available thread will execute it.  You will occasionally get lucky and end up with the same thread as before the continuation, but that's just by chance.

Comment: Here is a great link explaining why Console Application behave differently with async /await. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html